# How to access values returned by object's reference to void pointer?

Tags: c++

I am trying to access the object's value returned in the void pointer, how can i access those values x and y through void pointer variable.

How can I access the value returned in that void pointer ???

```
#include <iostream.h>
void* getDetector();

class DETECTOR
{
public:

    int x;
    int y;

    DETECTOR();
    ~DETECTOR();    
};

void* getDetector()
{
    return &DetectorObj;
}

DETECTOR::DETECTOR()
{
    x = 10;
    y = 20;
}

DETECTOR::~DETECTOR(){}

DETECTOR DetectorObj;

int main()
{
    void * getPtr = getDetector();

    cout<<getPtr->x;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which object? There is no `DetectorObj`

Comment: `static_cast<DETECTOR*>(getPtr)->x` ?

Comment: I know it's common to use Turbo C++ in Indian schools, but you should really take some time to learn modern C++, or even C++ after it was standardized in 1998 (Turbo C++ is *not* using standard C++, Turbo C++ is to old). [Here's a list of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), and there are also many free compilers and environments available to download.

Comment: You should not be using `<iostream.h>` — it is over 20 years antique!

Comment: Try not to use `void*` at all in C++. There's *very rarely* any good reason to.

Comment: And don't forget that in C++ (even before it was standardized) you needed to declare things before you use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the members of the object by returning the objects type and storing a pointer to that instead of a `void*`.

```
#include <iostream>
//DETECTOR definition..


DETECTOR DetectorObj;

DETECTOR* getDetector()
{
    return &DetectorObj;
}

int main()
{
    DETECTOR* getPtr = getDetector();

    cout<<getPtr->x;

    return 0;
}
```

There's no reason to return a `void*` here.

---

If you truly want to access them through `void*` then you can cast the result:

```
cout << static_cast<DETECTOR*>(getDetector())->x;
```

But this is considered bad bad practice. Please don't do this unless you're being held at gunpoint by your lecturer.

---

Also, it's `<iostream>`, not `<iostream.h>`, this is 2019.

Comment: If the code used `<iostream.h>`, there's no danger of it `using namespace std;`.  And the code used plain `cout` because there was no namespace support in the compiler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah right, good point. What even are namespaces.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Is it possible to access those values with void* variable.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya Yes, by casting it.

Comment: @SombreroChicken How can I cast that?

Comment: Your mum is considered bad bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `DetectorObj` is of type `DETECTOR` and has an instance:

```
int main()
{
    DETECTOR* getPtr = (DETECTOR*)getDetector();

    cout<<getPtr->x;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah, but WHY on earth would the object be casted to void* to be returned ? Change the interface instead and return the actual type, or a base type, or something sane.